# SAP UI5 Formatter How can I get Cell Id?

Tags: sapui5, formatter

Normally the cell ID will be generated by

```
this.getId
```

The console writes: this.getId() is not a function

I have a Datepicker; there I make the formatter :

```
<m:DatePicker value="{
            path: 'items>Lfdat', 
            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', 
            formatter: '.formatter.getColour',
```

I also can debug into the method getColour but I can't use this.getId().

Formatter.js looks this:

```
    getColour : function(sDate) {   
      var cell = this.getId() // is not a function
    }
```

Does somebody have a clue how I can read the Id and so change the background colour ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting id of Datepicker because in side Formatter.js `this` indicates the `window` object not the datepicker.

It is better to give an id to the date picker.

```
<m:DatePicker id="myDate" value="{
           ...
```

And then in Formatter.js

```
getColour : function(sDate) {   
      var cell = sap.ui.getCore().byId("myDate");
      // now cell is the reference to your datepicker
    }
```

Comment: This did not work  
            var cell = this.getView().byId("myDate");
                                  cell.addStyleClass("red");
                                 return sDate;
I make the Style in the Index.html Do you have a hint ?

Answer (score 0):

@Mario the formatter will not change format of the control, it is used only for the formatting the properties of the control.

I suggest

Instead of setting the background color for the table cell or DatePicker itself, can you use [sap.ui.core.ValueState](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.ValueState.html)

```
<m:DatePicker value="2016-Jan-08" valueState="{
                        path : 'name',
                        formatter : '.validate'}"/>
```

and the validate function is written in controller as below

```
validate : function(name)
       {
           return sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error;
       }
```

Comment: I try it, but the programm do not go in the validation, where do you have the validate method ? Shoul he start the formatter on init of the table ?

Comment: validate method i have written in controller of the view. if it start from "." means it should be controller..

Answer (score -1):

@Tuhin, id won't help, because it is in table

@Mario
your "this" is the controller, not the cell control.
you can do this to achieve what you looking for if I understand u correctly
example is based on ui table. not m table.
 **put the code in onInit**

```
   var someColumn = this.getView().byId("someColumn");
                someTemplate = someColumn .getTemplate();
                someTemplate .bindProperty("someproperty", {
                    parts : [{
                        path : 'somepath'
                    }, {
                        path : 'somepath1'
                    }],
                    formatter : Util.yourformatter
                });
```

if you do like this, you will get the proper "this" you want in the formatter

added8.4

```
<m:DatePicker value="{
            path: 'items>Lfdat', 
            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', 
            formatter: 'sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter.getColour',

this is example from sap, which defines a global formatter
```

////formatter starts here

jQuery.sap.declare("sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter");

sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter = {

```
getColor:function(){
```

// "this" will be the datepicker

}

};

//formatter ends here

// put this line in your controller

jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.demo.tdg.util.Formatter");

change the name space accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it. Where should i write this code? I will get the Id in the formatter.

Comment: I want to bind a colour to the background to some of the cells

Comment: http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2016/08/02/dynamic-cell-color-of-sapuitabletable-using-xml-views     if u want to color cell, this blog will help

Comment: @user1431989  I think what OP mean is cell in the DatePicker and not the actual cell in sap.m.table.

Comment: I want to color the cell or the datepicker it is not relevant, but how can i make an event and know which ros/ column i have in thos moment in tne formatter ?

Comment: did u really understand that blog? in your model, you have to prepare the data which tell which row/column should be colored

Comment: @Mario,  you want to color table cell or cell of the datepicker?

Comment: It is not important which of them is colored, but i need one :) , Yeah I read the blog , bt i don't wnat to color the whole colum just if the vaule is under on amount

Comment: @Mario it is. it only colors specific cell

Comment: @Mario the blog is using customdata to achieve the goal, my code is using formatter, which also colors cell only. don't be fooled by the variable-name.

Comment: Ok I want to color the cell in the background. For this i have to use the formatter , right ? but i get no reference on the cell

Comment: formatter is one way. the blog is using another way. just follow it.

Comment: Yeah but the blog have a fix color for each row i want not a fixed colour just when ex. more than 300 kg then it should be red but i can't get the reference in the formatter

Comment: it is not fixed.. man.
you manipulate your model data first. if the weight>300, rowdata.color="red"   bind this color to the custom data

Comment: if you don't want to change your model, then you can use formatter

Comment: Thanks man! But I not want to change the model, so i have the formatter and a xml view but i get not the right refernce on "this" in the formatter

Comment: from the beginning I know you are not getting the right "this". check my answer. don't put the formatter in your controller, I believe that is what you are doing.

Comment: Ok get the  cell, but the background isnt change i make this.addStyleClass("red"); and the style is in the index.html is this right ?

Comment: your css code please........and check at chrome dev tool to see why the class is not applied.